# What am I doing wrong in this Mongoose unique pre-save validation?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to create a User model, that has an unique username. Here's the code for it:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
});

UserSchema.virtual("password_confirmation").get(function() {
    return this.pw_conf;
}).set(function(value) {
    this.pw_conf = value;
});

UserSchema.path("username").required(true);
UserSchema.path("password").required(true);

UserSchema.pre("save",function(next, done) {
    var self = this;
    mongoose.models["User"].findOne({username : self.username},function(err, user) {
        if(user) {
            self.invalidate("user","username must be unique");
        }
        done();
    });
    next();
});

UserSchema.pre("save",function(next) {
    if(this.pw_conf !== this.password) {
        next(new Error("Must specify the password confirmation"));
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("User",UserSchema);
```

I was also testing to see if the uniqueness works:

```
var User = require("./users"),
  mongoose = require("mongoose");
var u = new User();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/my_database');

u.username = "me";
u.password = "password";
u.password_confirmation = "password";
u.save(function(err) {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    mongoose.disconnect();
});
```

Problem is, it doesn't. Each time I run the code, I get a new object created. I am aware that there are probably other ways of ensuring uniqueness, but I'd like to do it in this way. Shouldn't I be calling `done` after I handle the result of the `findOne` method? Am I calling `next` wrong?

Comment: as of 2022, all you need to do is putting "unique:true" into the field's setting, mongoose will take care of the rest for you

Answer (score 29, accepted):

To use [parallel middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#parallel) (with `next` and `done` parameters), you need to pass `true` as the second parameter.

Beyond that, there are two possibilities:

Your `self.invalidate` call should be referencing `"username"` instead of `"user"`.  If that doesn't fix it, you can fail things explicitly by passing an Error object to `done` if you want to abort the save operation:

```
UserSchema.pre("save", true, function(next, done) {
    var self = this;
    mongoose.models["User"].findOne({username: self.username}, function(err, user) {
        if(err) {
            done(err);
        } else if(user) {
            self.invalidate("username", "username must be unique");
            done(new Error("username must be unique"));
        } else {
            done();
        }
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: It worked, but the error format isn't the same so if you're building an API and counting on the error object format you're probably going to have issues with that approach. I've tested the https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-unique-validator and it worked like a charm for me. The error object is pretty much the same.

Comment: for me, this didn't work, I had to change the signature of the function to have only one argument (next) and then calling next with error or next without parameters accordingly

Comment: @Matus There are two types of `pre` [middleware](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html): parallel (with the `next`, and `done` params), and serial (with just the `next`).

Answer (score 33):

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-unique is the way to go. It uses actual MongoDb indexes to make sure that your field is unique. No need for `.pre` middleware.

Enjoy!

Comment: Yeah but no custom error message.. And there is no way to make a difference between 2 different unique errors on the same document. See https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoose-orm/BX7kz0BwLjk/JWuvD_p4hYcJ

Comment: +1 for what @YvesM. said, and also as per Mongoose docs: "NOTE: violating the constraint **returns an E11000 error from MongoDB** when saving, **not a Mongoose validation error**."

Comment: it now does feature a custom error message: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-error-messages

Answer (score 5):

There's a really good plugin for mongoose that's really easy to install and use. The documentation is excellent and it worked for me first time.

But there is an issue with re-saving.

https://npmjs.org/package/mongoose-unique-validator

Comment: Usually against bringing more modules into projects, but I also think that this is a must if you're going to do a lot of validation and it pretty much doesn't require any refactor to integrate

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using an asynchronous validator to catch the error?

```
UserSchema.path('username').validate(function (value, done) {
  User.count({ username: value }, function (error, count) {
    // Return false if an error is thrown or count > 0
    done(!(error || count));
  });
}, 'unique');
```

Comment: done undefined ?