# MongoDB unique index custom error message E11000

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is there a way to set custom error message for 'E11000 duplicate key error' in MongoDB?
(Preferably, using Mongoose):

```
userSchema.index({ name: 1, email: 1 }, { unique: true });
```

Comment: what is better:  generate a new error or `userSchema.findOne({email})` and create a simple conditional before going into the database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) You can use mongoose-unique-validator.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator.

This makes error handling much easier, since you will get a Mongoose validation error when you attempt to violate a unique constraint, rather than an E11000 error from MongoDB.

2) 
Referenced in [What am I doing wrong in this Mongoose unique pre-save validation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872556/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-mongoose-unique-pre-save-validation)
you can also use pre save method in express

```
Schema.pre("save",function(next, done) {
//Here you can search if the record already exists and return custom message.
next();
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can easily customize and display error messages for `unique: true` validation errors using `mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation`.

To do so simply use the package [mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation](https://github.com/matteodelabre/mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation):

```
npm install --save mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation
```

Then you can simply use it as a global plugin (as below) or per schema.

```
const beautifyUnique = require('mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation');

mongoose.plugin(beautifyUnique);
```

For full insight and reference, please see this [comment](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/2284#issuecomment-320810641) and the [Readme](https://github.com/matteodelabre/mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation) on GitHub.

You may also want to use the package [mongoose-validation-error-transform](https://github.com/niftylettuce/mongoose-validation-error-transform) for displaying Mongoose validation error message(s).

Answer (score 2):

No, not without changing the MongoDB source code and recompiling it with the new error message. You can swap out the message for one more to your liking with your application code. You could, for example, just wrap the index build call in a function that will return a different error message if a unique key constraint violation error occurs.