# Mongoose.js Unique Validation

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

NOTE: there's an edit at the bottom of the question:

Can I check the database for uniqueness using either a custom validator or a pre hook in a Mongoose.js model file. I am aware that I can check it in the controller, but I'd rather put it in the model file with the rest of the validators just for consistency.

I am also aware there is an npm package called mongoose-unique-validator that does this but I'm no fan of installing a library to do what should be one to five lines of code tops.

Mongoose also has a "unique" property that will throw an error if the item is not unique. But their documents clearly state this is not a validator. And the error it throws does not get routed the same as the validation errors.

Here is the relevant parts of the model file. This will check the db and if there is no dup then it creates the article but if there is a dup it throws an error but not a validation error which is what I want. If I simply return false if there is a dup it just ignores the validation and creates the duplicate article. This is no doubt related to Promises/Async. Here are the relevant Mongoose docs https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators. And they talk about how the unique property is not a validator https://mongoosejs.com/docs/faq.html.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const articleSchema = new Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Title is required"],
    // unique: true, 
    // isAsync: true,
    validate: {
      validator: function(value) {
        this.constructor.findOne({title: value}, (err, article) => {
          if (err || !article) { 
            return true;
          } else {
            // return false;
            throw new Error('Duplicate');
          }
        });
      },
      message: (props) => `Title "${props.value}" is already in use.`
    },
  },
  content: { type: String, required: true }
});
```

EDIT: I figured this out, but it only works when creating a new article, not on updates. So the question is still open but the focus is on how to get it to work on updates. On update Mongoose does not treat "this" as the document object like it does on create. Instead "this" is the request object, and "this.constructor.findOne()" throws the error "this.constructor.findOne is not a function". Here's the revised validator:

```
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: [true, "Title is required"],
    isAsync: true,
    validate: {
      validator: async function(value) {
        const article = await this.constructor.findOne({title: value});
        if (article) {
          throw new Error(`${value} is already in use.`);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can yo check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11872556/what-am-i-doing-wrong-in-this-mongoose-unique-pre-save-validation. It is similar. Or you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-unique-validator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that question. I hadn't seen it. But it doesn't appear to give me what I want. And actually I figured out how to do it for a new article but it doesn't work on update. So I'll edit my question with that new info.

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#update-validators Have you tried turn on validators option ?

Comment: Yes, it's on. The other validators, like is required, work on update. It in fact is trying to run the custom validator on update, but because of the "this" issue, it can't reference the object. The above throws an error on update unless I wrap a conditional around it to only run on create.

Answer (score 0):

Your `validator` function will only run the script and it not pass any callback or promise to mongoose, so mongoose assume that the validator return true and continue the process.
According to the document, you should return promise or use callback.

Promise:

```
validator: function(value) {
    var here = this;
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        here.constructor.findOne({title: value}, (err, article) => {
        if (err || !article) { 
          resolve(true);
        } else {
          resolve(false);
        }
      });
    })
}
```

Callback: (need to set `isAsync: true`)

```
validator: function(value, cb) {
      this.constructor.findOne({title: value}, (err, article) => {
        if (err || !article) { 
          cb(true);
        } else {
          cb(false, "Content is used");
        }
     });
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of those worked. The first created the article even when there was a dup. The second throws an error that callback is not a function. I fixed the typos in your answer before trying them and still no success. But actually I did figure it out, only to find a new problem. This.constructor only works on create actions not update. Turns out Mongoose deals with update in a different manner so I'm still not home free.